How do you prevent camera orientation from flipping once it passes certain threshhold in ThreeJS?
I have a scene where I loaded a model of a space ship, the model always moves in the z direction, and I can control it's movements with 'WASD'. I placed the camera right behind the model, so as it moves about in the scene the camera follows it
This is the entire component, just without the imports or proptype hints
const Boeing = ({params}) => {
    // 1. Unpack `params`
    const {
        boeingRef
    } = params;

    // 2. Make `camera` object
    const { camera, gl, scene } = useThree()

    // 3. Make ref to the container that houses the Spyro model
    const groupRef = useRef()

    // 4. Object to store key presses
    const [keysPressed, setKeysPressed] = useState({})

    // 5. Pause stuff
    const [pause, setPause] = useState(false)

    // Load the GLTF model
    const gltf = useLoader(GLTFLoader, model)

    const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
        setKeysPressed((prevKeys) => ({
            ...prevKeys,
            [event.code]: true,
        }))
    }

    const handleKeyUp = (event) => {
        setKeysPressed((prevKeys) => ({
            ...prevKeys,
            [event.code]: false,
        }))
        if (event.code === 'Space') {
            setPause((prevPaused) => !prevPaused)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
        window.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp)

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
            window.removeEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp)
        }
    }, [])

    useFrame(() => {
        if (boeingRef.current) {
            camera.up.set(0, 1, 0);
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            let groupSpeed = pause ? 0 : 0.1  // Determines the speed of zTranslation on the group
            const xGroupRotationSpeed = 0.01
            const yGroupRotationSpeed = 0.01
            const zGroupRotationSpeed = 0.01
            const xBoeingRotationSpeed = 0.01
            const yBoeingRotationSpeed = 0.01
            const zBoeingRotationSpeed = 0.01
            const maxPitch = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(5); // Max pitch in radians
            const maxRoll = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(30); // Max roll in radians
            const maxYaw = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(30); // Max yaw in radians

            // Pitch controls
            if (keysPressed['KeyW']) {
                if (boeingRef.current.rotation.x < maxPitch) {
                    boeingRef.current.rotateX(xBoeingRotationSpeed) //  Visually Pitch up
                }
                groupRef.current.rotateX(xGroupRotationSpeed) // Pitch up
            }
            if (keysPressed['KeyS']) {
                if (boeingRef.current.rotation.x > - maxPitch) {
                    boeingRef.current.rotateX(-xBoeingRotationSpeed) // Visually Pitch down
                }
                groupRef.current.rotateX(-xGroupRotationSpeed) // Pitch down
            }
            if (!keysPressed['KeyW'] && !keysPressed['KeyS']) {
                if (boeingRef.current.rotation.x > 0) {
                    boeingRef.current.rotation.x = THREE.MathUtils.lerp(boeingRef.current.rotation.x, 0, 0.009);
                }
                else if (boeingRef.current.rotation.x < 0) {
                    boeingRef.current.rotation.x = THREE.MathUtils.lerp(boeingRef.current.rotation.x, 0, 0.009);
                }
            }

            // Yaw controls
            if (keysPressed['KeyA']) {
                if (boeingRef.current.rotation.z < maxRoll) {
                    boeingRef.current.rotateZ(zBoeingRotationSpeed); // Visually Roll left
                }
                if (boeingRef.current.rotation.y < maxYaw) {
                    boeingRef.current.rotateY(yBoeingRotationSpeed); // Visually Yaw Left
                }
                groupRef.current.rotateY(yGroupRotationSpeed); // Yaw left
            }
            if (keysPressed['KeyD']) {
                if (boeingRef.current.rotation.z > -maxRoll) {
                    boeingRef.current.rotateZ(-zBoeingRotationSpeed); // Visually Roll right
                }
                if (boeingRef.current.rotation.y > -maxYaw) {
                    boeingRef.current.rotateY(-yBoeingRotationSpeed); // Visually Yaw Right
                }
                groupRef.current.rotateY(-yGroupRotationSpeed); // Yaw right
            }
            if (!keysPressed['KeyA'] && !keysPressed['KeyD']) {
                if (boeingRef.current.rotation.z > 0) {
                    boeingRef.current.rotation.z = THREE.MathUtils.lerp(boeingRef.current.rotation.z, 0, 0.03); // Damped reset left
                }
                else if (boeingRef.current.rotation.z < 0) {
                    boeingRef.current.rotation.z = THREE.MathUtils.lerp(boeingRef.current.rotation.z, 0, 0.03); // Damped reset right
                }

                if (boeingRef.current.rotation.y > 0) {
                    boeingRef.current.rotation.y = THREE.MathUtils.lerp(boeingRef.current.rotation.y, 0, 0.03)
                }
                else if (boeingRef.current.rotation.y < 0) {
                    boeingRef.current.rotation.y = THREE.MathUtils.lerp(boeingRef.current.rotation.y, 0, 0.03)
                }
            }

            // Roll controls
            if (keysPressed['KeyQ']) {
                boeingRef.current.rotateZ(-zBoeingRotationSpeed) // Roll left
                groupRef.current.rotateZ(-zGroupRotationSpeed) // Roll left
            }
            if (keysPressed['KeyE']) {
                boeingRef.current.rotateZ(zBoeingRotationSpeed) // Roll right
                groupRef.current.rotateZ(zGroupRotationSpeed) // Roll right
            }

            // Continuously move forward
            groupRef.current.translateZ(groupSpeed)

            // Update camera to follow the plane
            const offset = pause ? new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -2) : new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 2)
            const position = groupRef.current.position.clone().add(offset.applyQuaternion(groupRef.current.quaternion))
            camera.position.lerp(position, 0.03)
            camera.lookAt(groupRef.current.position)
        }
    })

    return (
        <>
            <group ref={groupRef} position={[10,10,-100]}>
                <primitive
                    ref={boeingRef}
                    object={gltf.scene}
                    scale={[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]} // Adjust the scale as needed
                />
            </group>
        </>
    )
}

And this was the App.jsx with the Canvas component
function App() {

    // Params for Boeing
    const boeingRef = useRef()
    const boeingParams = {
        boeingRef
    };

    return (
        <Canvas className="App"
                style={{width: innerWidth, height: innerHeight, backgroundColor: "black"}}
                camera={{
                    far: 1000,
                    near: 0.01,
                    fov: 75,
                    position: [0, 0, 0],
                    aspect: innerWidth / innerHeight,
                    type: 'PerspectiveCamera'
                }}
        >
            <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
            <Boeing params={boeingParams}/>
            <axesHelper />
        </Canvas>
    )
}

The issue in particular is if you try to control the pitch, so rotating about the X axis, the space ship effectively flies in a circular motion as if on a rollercoaster. At the top of this rollercoaster, the camera inverts or flips. This create the illusion that all of my controls are not flipped as well
So what I am trying to understand is how to prevent this camera flipping from happening. I tried setting the camera up direction in the useFrame hook, but it didn't help. I also tried changing all the rotations related to controls to all use quternions, but same problem exists where the camera will flip orientations at a certain point
I thought setting the up direction would be sufficient, does anyone know how to solve the problem or if there's something I overlooked? Thanks <3

This is a question that pops up alot so I'll add here what ended up finally working for me
You have to track and update the up vector consistently in useFrame
You initiliaze it first somewhere in your component
const upVector = useRef(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0));

And inside your useFrame you want to calculate the cross product between your object's forward and right vectors, and update upVector
// Calculate forward and up vectors
const forward = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,-1).applyQuaternion(boeingRef.current.quaternion);
const right = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0).applyQuaternion(boeingRef.current.quaternion);

// Calculate cross product
upVector.current.crossVectors(right, forward).normalize();

// Set camera up vector
camera.up.copy(upVector.current);

